# Payment Processor Error - Can't find valid value for PP

Tags: error, payment-processor

I just installed Drupal 7 and CiviCRM 4.7.30 from the CiviCRM install package. The install worked just fine, but now that I'm trying to 'configure' CiviCRM I've run into errors when setting up Payment Processor or trying to create price sets.

For the Payment Processor, I'm getting CRM_Financial_BAO_FinancialTypeAccount::validateRelationship ... when I debug I get 'could not find valid value for pp'

For the New Price Set issue, I'm getting DB Error: Syntax Error.

I can't find anything on the support wiki, documentation, or WWW that would provide me assistance with these issues. I'm hoping someone in this exchange will be able to guide me. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you have turned off CiviContribute component.

Comment: I did ... you are correct. I thought the 'contribute' feature was for donations and disabled it to save processing. I don't remember reading about this as the main financial feature but it is working properly now. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, you will need to enable CiviContribute component if you are using payment processor  or financial type.

Comment: Can we close this post as Answered?